# How to rename the default project in sbt

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have a multi-project setup using sbt version 0.13.5

My built.sbt looks like:

```
lazy val common = (project in file("app-common"))....
lazy val models = (project in file("app-common"))....
lazy val services = (project in file("app-common"))....
```

When I am in sbt, and I type: projects I see:

```
common
default-d4d83c
models
services
```

It is such a pain to type the entire default-a2343  (ok I might be stretching the level of pain I feel, but I am hoping it can get a bit better heeh).

## 1 What is this default project because I am pretty sure I am not defining it anywher

## 2 How can I rename this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is related to this statement from the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html):

> If a project is not defined for the root directory in the build, sbt creates a default one that aggregates all other projects in the build.

which I take to mean that unless you define a project name for the directory ".", one will be generated automatically. This [github commit](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/96b2ca7ce4fc15124266b12ccaed8e49c4af5634) seems relevant, and looks like it is using a hash from the absolute name of the directory. Simply defining `project in file(".")...` would seem to be the solution.